A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. That's wht the app doesn't work
This is error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Mucahit\Desktop\Mobil Uygulama\flutter_dersleri\android\app\build.gradle' line: 28
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
\> 'void com.android.build.api.variant.ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtension.registerSourceType(java.lang.String)'
* Try:
\> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
\> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
\> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BU�LD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
app/src/buid.gradle
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'//This is error

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_dersleri"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.2"))
}

I ran the application. I didn't expect to get an error.
Please help me
I don't think there is a bug in my plugin. Could you help
